# ConstraintLayout baseline alignment support for custom view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I had created custom view based on `LinearLayout` with two `TextView`, i placed it in `ConstraintLayout` but i can not align other view to baseline of that custom view. Am i able to define baseline in my customview?

Comment: what does `View#getBaseline()` return?

Comment: @pskink right now `-1`

Comment: so read `View#getBaseline` documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved by override `View#getBaseline` method

i had set it to `getBaseline` of one of child view

Comment: i would use min/max of two child `TextView#getBaseline()`